Issue with Inactive Volume Analysis Toolbar in TREND-POINT
I am currently using the TREND-POINT software to perform volume analysis using mesh after loading two txt format point cloud data files. However, the buttons in the volume analysis toolbar are grayed out and inactive, making them unusable.
Initially, when I loaded the files, the buttons were active. However, at some point, they became grayed out and I am unable to use them. I have tried reloading the files and restarting the software, but the issue persists.
Could you advise on the following points?

Possible causes and solutions for this issue.
Any necessary settings or procedures to resolve this.
Recommended troubleshooting methods.

